# SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR for only values in current year

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerpivot, tabular, ssas-2012

I'm trying to show the value from prior year for products. I only want the products that are present in the current year to show.

What I would like:

> Product SamePeriodSalesLastYear
>
> 1,          $10
>
> 2,          $12

What I am getting:

> Product  SamePeriodSalesLastYear
>
> 1          $10
>
> 2          $12
>
> 3          $8 --Product 3 has no sales in the current year

`CALCULATE([Sum of ProductSales], SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR(D_DATE[DATE]))`

OR

`CALCULATE([Sum of ProductSales]), PARALLELPERIOD(D_DATE[DATE],-12,month))`

Any help on this would be really appreciated.

Thank you